# Handle Angular Click event with a overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to get all click over my overlay, and i dont know angular is ignoring him when i click at another element under the overlay.

I created this stackblitz to see if the problem happens in another place, but i had the similar problem.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sjkwkc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```css
.carta {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(163,161,163,1);
  background-color: #fff;
}

.carta:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(163,161,163,1);
  border-color: var(--preto);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carta .overlay {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mao">
  <div class="carta">
    <div (click)="selecionaCarta($event, 'test')" class="overlay"></div>
    <span class="nome ouro">Here</span>
    <span class="naipe"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because both your overlay and text is positioned absolute. In your case you want the overlay to be on top.

Adding a z-index to your overlay class should fix the issue.

E.g.

```
.carta .overlay {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index: 10; // <<< this
}
```